# group by without making any calculation

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to know, if there is a function in which you can group the lines based on a column(like dealer) but without making any account (sum,mean,etc)

Example:

| Dealer | city |
| --- | --- |
| A | x |
| B | y |
| C | z |
| A | h |
| A | j |
| A | f |
| B | s |

Would like to be:

| Dealer | city |
| --- | --- |
| A | x |
|  | h |
|  | j |
|  | f |
| B | y |
|  | s |
| C | z |

Comment: Do you want to have a multiindex or just to sort your dataframe.  In the first case `reindex` would work, in the second `sort_values` would work (or `sort_index` if `Dealer` is already the index).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data frame is named `df`, you want to sort using `sort_values:

```
df.sort_values(by=['Dealer'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

The `inplace=True` will set the `df` to be used like this throughout its lifetime, if you don't want to keep the df as sorted then have `inplace=False`.

Also if you would like to set the index to 'Dealer' so there is not an extra column when calling `head()` or something, then use this before sorting:

```
df.set_index('Dealer', inplace=True)
```

Comment: The objective is not to sort, but to group all the sales with the same dealer. Its like using a groupby function, but which doesnt need any function (like sum, mean, etc)

Comment: Im not seeing how this will differ from `sort_values`?

Comment: Have you tried this? Is it not what you want?